# How to get Scroll Spy to work in Meteor/Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm trying to get scroll spy to work in a Meteor app with Bootstrap 3. I have the Bootstrap3-LESS Meteorite package installed but Meteor doesn't allow  tags, which seems to be a dependency of Scroll Spy... there is a JS method to do it but when I try that I get errors compiling when running meteor

Anyone have any solution(s)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and ScrollSpy for a sidebar navigation menu in a Meteor project. I'll include my template and JS file below. I should mention a couple things about the JS...I'm using Iron Router (https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) and named anchors weren't working, so I wrote the click event handler to mimic the expected behavior. The other thing to note is that you may have to play around with the offset values for `affix`, but hopefully this gives you an idea.

**Template - build.html**

```
<template name="home_build">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 hidden-xs hidden-print">
            <nav id="my-nav" class="affix">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#unit-summary"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Unit Summary</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#desired-results"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Desired Results</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#instruction"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Instruction</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div> <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8">
            <div id="unit-summary" style="padding-top:44px;">
                <h3>Unit Summary</h3>
                <p>Lots of content goes here...</p>
            </div>
            <div id="desired-results" style="padding-top:44px;">
                <h3>Desired Results</h3>
                <p>Lots of content goes here...</p>
            </div>
            <div id="instruction" style="padding-top:44px;">
                <h3>Instruction</h3>
                <p>Lots of content goes here...</p>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /.col -->
    </div> <!-- /.row -->
</template>
```

**JS - build.js**

```
Template.home_build.rendered = function () {
    var w = $(window),
        b = $(document.body),
        id,
        navHeight = $('#top-bar').outerHeight(true) + 20;

    b.scrollspy({
        target: '#my-nav',
        offset: navHeight
    });

    w.on('load', function () {
        b.scrollspy('refresh');
    });

    w.resize(function () {
        clearTimeout(id);
        id = setTimeout(function () { b.scrollspy('refresh'); }, 500);
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        var sideNav = $('#my-nav');

        sideNav.affix({
            offset: {
                top: function () {
                    var offsetTop = sideNav.offset().top,
                        sideNavMargin = parseInt(sideNav.children(0).css('margin-top'), 10),
                        navOuterHeight = $('#top-bar').height(),
                        topOff = offsetTop + navOuterHeight + sideNavMargin - 12;
                    return (this.top = topOff);
                },
                bottom: function () {
                    return (this.bottom = $('#footer').outerHeight(true));
                }
            }
        });
    }, 100);
};

Template.home_build.events({
    'click #my-nav a': function (e) {
        var t = e.currentTarget,
            el = document.getElementById(t.getAttribute('href').substr(1));
        if (!!el && el.scrollIntoView) {
            el.scrollIntoView();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Some Javascript Methods depends on the Browser and can't call at the server side. In this case Meteor throws errors. Bootstrap is a client-side framework so be sure to call the JS method on client only.

tip: To get a closer answer provide the code where you try to call the JS-method. The exact error message is helpful too.

Comment: I tried doing what you said, I included the code ($('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar-example' })
) client side only but still no go, it compiles fine now but no joy for scroll spy..

Answer (score 1):

It may be necessary within your templates to put your anchors in `{{#constant}}{{/constant}}` blocks due to the way that the reactivity in the templating works.

Also ensure that the scrollspy javascript is actually included in the bootstrap packages folders.  It could just be that you don't actually have the javascript for scrollspy.  You can open the bootstrap.js in the packages folder and do a find for scrollspy.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem with bootstrap carousel and affix.After I have moved my normally functioning html+js to Meteor the carousel and affix just stopped working.My config is :Meteor+twbs:bootstrap+iron:router.
As a solution I propose to add the following code to your JS client file for affix+scrollspy to work properly:

```
Template.aboutus.rendered = function () {
//Affix initialisation  
$("#myaffix").affix({
    offset: { 
        top: 400 //data-offset-top="400"
    }
});
console.log("affix initiated");
//Scrollspy initialisation  
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#myScrollspy' });
console.log("scrollspy initiated");
```

};

I think the main reason for the problem is that by default the scrollspy function is binded to body, and body might be ommited in your template, so you should add it (I did it on the ApplicationLayout level).
Another reason might be that bootstrap scripts are loaded before the template is rendered, so the funcions binded to certain tags just dont work.
Thats why you need to reinitiate bootstrap functions to work properly.

The same thing concerns Corousel function. It needs to be reinitiated after the template is rendered.

```
Template.main_content.rendered = function () {
//Carousel setup  
$("#mycarousel").carousel( { interval: 2000 } );
console.log("carousel initiated");
};
```